# using variables in awk print

Tags: awk

The contents of **myfile.txt** file are as follows:

```
| dbname                 |
| dbname1                |
| dbname2                |
```

The following command is expected to generate the output as shown below:

```
cat myfile.txt | awk '{print "mysql -uroot -Bse \"call mysql.p_check_fk_constraint_violations('\'$2\'','\''%'\'')\""}'
```

Expected Output:

```
mysql -uroot -Bse "call mysql.p_check_fk_constraint_violations('dbname','%')"
mysql -uroot -Bse "call mysql.p_check_fk_constraint_violations('dbname1','%')"
mysql -uroot -Bse "call mysql.p_check_fk_constraint_violations('dbname2','%')"
```

But the actual output is:

```
mysql -uroot -Bse "call mysql.p_check_fk_constraint_violations('','%')"
```

How do I add the database names in awk statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it -

```
[jaypal~/Temp]$ cat db.file 
| dbname                 |
| dbname1                |
| dbname2                |
```

Here we are substituting the second field with your text and using "&" matches the field getting substituted.

```
[jaypal~/Temp]$ awk -F\| '{sub($2,"mysql \-uroot \-Bse \"call mysql.p_check_fk_constraint_violations\(&,\%\)\""); print $2}' db.file 
mysql -uroot -Bse "call mysql.p_check_fk_constraint_violations( dbname                 ,%)"
mysql -uroot -Bse "call mysql.p_check_fk_constraint_violations( dbname1                ,%)"
mysql -uroot -Bse "call mysql.p_check_fk_constraint_violations( dbname2                ,%)"
```

Alternatively as Teudimundo suggested, you can do -

```
[jaypal~/Temp]$ cat db.file | awk '{print "mysql -uroot -Bse \"call mysql.p_check_fk_constraint_violations("$2",'%')\""}'
mysql -uroot -Bse "call mysql.p_check_fk_constraint_violations(dbname,%)"
mysql -uroot -Bse "call mysql.p_check_fk_constraint_violations(dbname1,%)"
mysql -uroot -Bse "call mysql.p_check_fk_constraint_violations(dbname2,%)"
```

**UPDATE**

```
[jaypal~/Temp]$ cat db.file | awk '{print "mysql -uroot -Bse \"call mysql.p_check_fk_constraint_violations('"'"'"$2"'"'"', '"'"'%'"'"')"}'
mysql -uroot -Bse "call mysql.p_check_fk_constraint_violations('dbname', '%')
mysql -uroot -Bse "call mysql.p_check_fk_constraint_violations('dbname1', '%')
mysql -uroot -Bse "call mysql.p_check_fk_constraint_violations('dbname2', '%')

[jaypal~/Temp]$ awk '{ print $2 }' db.file | awk '{sub($1,"mysql \-uroot \-Bse \"call mysql.p_check_fk_constraint_violations\('"'"'&'"'"','"'"'%'"'"'\)\""); print $0}'
mysql -uroot -Bse "call mysql.p_check_fk_constraint_violations('dbname','%')"
mysql -uroot -Bse "call mysql.p_check_fk_constraint_violations('dbname1','%')"
mysql -uroot -Bse "call mysql.p_check_fk_constraint_violations('dbname2','%')"
```

Comment: close. But I expect ('dbname','%')"

Answer (score 1):

here : `'" $2 "'` you are closing the first awk `'` char, and so " $2 " is interpreted by the shell.

Answer (score 1):

You're running into problems because of the single quotes, as Teudimundo said. To fix it, you need to replace each single quote `'` that you'd like to embed with this `'"'"'`, giving this awk command:

```
awk '{print "mysql -uroot -Bse \"call mysql.p_check_fk_constraint_violations('"'"'$2'"'"', '"'"'%'"'"')"}'
```

This works because the `'"'"'` first ends the single-quoted string for the awk command, begins a new double-quoted string containing a single quote, then starts a new single-quoted string with the rest of the awk command. Since adjacent strings are concatenated in the shell, this strange-seeming approach produces the string you need.

Comment: it is printing $2 for all 3 lines. Does not substitute variables.

Comment: It would, just need to add another layer of double quotes. :)

Answer (score 0):

It suppose that it will be far better to use *mysql* procedure, instead of jumping in and out of *mysql* using *shell* scripting ...
I'm not familiar with *mysql*'s procedural language, but I'm sure that if you search Internet 
you can quickly come up with a simple procedure, something like this:

```
delimiter //
drop procedure run_proc //

create procedure run_proc()
begin
  declare done boolean default 0;
  declare l_db_name varchar(100);
  declare cur_db_names cursor
   for
     select 
       schema_name 
     from 
       information_schema.schemata;
  declare continue handler for 
    sqlstate '02000' set done=1;

   open cur_db_names;
   repeat
   fetch cur_db_names into l_db_name;
     call mysql.p_check_fk_constraint_violations(l_db_name,'%');
   until done end repeat;
   close cur_db_names;
end;
//

delimiter ;

call run_proc;
```